# How to re-zip as a .jet file

Tags: sqlite, archive, 7zip, jet

I have a .sqlite file and the developer zip it as a .jet file. Now I can open it with 7zip, I can edit the db but at the end I couldn't re-zip again as a .jet file. I tried every solution that I saw on the internet, but none of them answer to me.

If someone wants to take a look, file download link.

https://wetransfer.com/downloads/ea5a329dff6b4ca48363a6faca2b17af20190516110040/2b647b

Any help would be great.

Comment: What happens when you try to to re-zip it? What are some of the solutions you tried?

Comment: when i try re-zip it, i get file.7z, file.bzip2, file.gzip, file.tar, file.wim, file.xz extensions.but it should be file.jet

i tried some code combinations, some softwares and changing extension manually.